# Scraping a website to get a particular value in PHP.

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to scrape a cetrain value off a website: http://www.gitanjalijewels.com/

I am using the following code:

```
<?php 


$data = file_get_contents('http://www.gitanjalijewels.com/category.php?id=39');
$regex = '/GOLD RATES:: (.+?) ,/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match); 
echo $match[1];
```

?>

However the result I get is:

***array(0) { }***

Unable to determine what might be wrong? Can anyone please direct me to towards the right direction?

Comment: please for the millionth time use a dom parser.

Comment: PHP is not my domain, I am not able to find anything easy apart from this, I read about the most voted answer on SO,about how regex can mess up things but do I have an option!

Comment: Plus this website does not support DOM, its messed up for reasons!

Comment: If the browser can display it, other DOM parsers are able to parse it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use a DOM parser.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.gitanjalijewels.com/');

foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/li/marquee/') as $element)                                     
{ 
       echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
GOLD RATES::(24kt999:--Rs.2868), (24kt995:--Rs.2841), (22kt:--Rs.2675), (18kt:--Rs.2236)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$regex = '/GOLD RATES::[\s]?(.+?)[\s]?,/si';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output :

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(32) "GOLD RATES::(24kt999:--Rs.2868),"
  [1] =>
  string(19) "(24kt999:--Rs.2868)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.gitanjalijewels.com/category.php?id=39");

$matches = array();
preg_match("/GOLD RATES::[^\>]+/", $html, $matches);
print("<pre>");
var_dump($matches);
print("</pre>");

if( count($matches) > 0 ){
    $html = $matches[0];
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/\(([^:]+)\:([^\)]+)\)/", $html, $matches);

    $goldPrice = array();
    if( count($matches) > 0){
        for($i = 0; $i<count($matches[1]); $i++)
            $goldPrice[ $matches[1][$i] ] = $matches[2][$i];
    }
    print("<pre>");
    var_dump($goldPrice);
    print("</pre>");
}

result:
array(4) {
    ["24kt999"]=>
        string(9) "--Rs.2868"
    ["24kt995"]=>
        string(9) "--Rs.2841"
    ["22kt"]=>
        string(9) "--Rs.2675"
    ["18kt"]=>
        string(9) "--Rs.2236"
}
```